# How to wrap UITableView with UINavigationController?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I'm new to iPhone development and I have a trouble trying to implement UINavigationController.

I have implemented ViewController in following way:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UITableViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UITableView *table;  

    /* added later but it dont know what to do to show it first*/
    IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController; 
    }

@end
```

[image]

This TableView works good. But I want to wrap around navigation controller to be able to show next view after row-click.
The problem that I don't undrstand what should I do with NIB file. I have drag-n-dropped there UIViewController - but I can't set it as view. Because I cant drag connection from file owner's view to UIViewController. What should I do to make this look like Table-in-Navigation, not plain table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UINavigationViewController will own the UITableViewController. So the AppDelegate will setup the UINavigationViewController and then the top of the stack will start out as your table view controller.

Comment: So how to make 'UINavigationViewController will own the UITableViewController' ? Do I have to change inheritance of FirstViewController ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in your `tableView:didSelectCellAtIndexPath:` method, make a new controller, then push it on your navigation controller.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewContrller:controller animated:YES];
```

then release the controller, because the navigation controller retains it.

```
[controller release];
```

Comment: this will only work if your navigation controller is set up as the windows view